# aws_s3.table_import_from_s3 wont terminate on postgres

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

i cant seem to find anything on this anywhere so maybe y'all will have some answers .

we have an rds postgres instance on 14.7

recently upgraded from 11

after the upgrade we have had instances where sometimes the aws_s3.table_import_from_s3
will sometimes get stuck for days on files that are relatively small. usually we would just do pg_cancel_backend or pg_terminate_backend but that does not seem to work and it keeps the lock on the table its trying to import into.

anyone else run into this?

we have run pg_cancel_backend
and pg_terminate_backend but that does not seem to work and it keeps the lock on the table its trying to import into.

the only way we have been able to clear the locks and stop the transaction is to restart the server.

Answer (score 0):

We also started to see the same issue (~4 weeks ago) in a code that was running during one year using the same function without problems.
We contacted the support of AWS and they are investigating it but they didn't provide many details. Seems that this has happened before for other db engines and versions.

- Fixed an issue where, in rare cases, an import from the aws_s3 extension fails to complete.

from:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraPostgreSQLReleaseNotes/AuroraPostgreSQL.Updates.html

Probably it could be a issue with aws_s3 extension.

we also have a rds postgres instance on 14.1.
we are still waiting for a AWS response on our ticket.